# How to get text of selected node using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup for the first time and not able to get the idea about how I can extract the text from some specific node. Here is my code

html:

```
...
<p class="dsm">...</p>
<ul class="also">
    <li>once as the adjective <i class="ab">abdrea</i> (<span class="at">groups</span>)</li>
    <li>twice as the noun <i class="ab">shokdia</i> (<span class="at">techs</span>)</li>
</ul>
...
```

python:

```
current_page = urlopen(url)
current_soup = BeautifulSoup(current_page, 'html.parser')
derivative_list = current_soup.select('p.dsm + ul.also li')
for li in derivative_list:
    print(li)
```

output:

```
<li>once as the adjective <i class="ab">abdrea</i> (<span class="at">groups</span>)</li>
<li>twice as the noun <i class="ab">shokdia</i> (<span class="at">techs</span>)</li>
```

Its outputting the correct list items, but what I want to get is text values of i.ab and span.at, something like

**desired output:**

```
abdrea, groups
shokdia, techs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting a list of all the `<li>` tags, simply iterate over them and find the texts of the `<i class="ab">` and `<span class="at">` tags individually.

```
for li in soup.select('p.dsm + ul.also li'):
    print(li.i.text, li.span.text)
# abdrea groups
# shokdia techs
```

If there are other `<i>` and `<span>` tags inside the `<li>` tags, you can use `find()` on the `li` variable.

```
for li in soup.select('p.dsm + ul.also li'):
    print(li.find('i', class_='ab').text, li.find('span', class_='at').text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Exact answer you looking for:

```
data = """<ul class="also">
    <li>once as the adjective <i class="ab">abdrea</i> (<span class="at">groups</span>)</li>
    <li>twice as the noun <i class="ab">shokdia</i> (<span class="at">techs</span>)</li>
</ul>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
i_data, span_data= zip([x.text for x in page_soup.find_all("i")], [y.text for y in page_soup.find_all("span")])
 
print(i_data )
print(span_data)
```

## output:

```
(u'abdrea', u'groups')
(u'shokdia', u'techs')
```